# Interpreting axiom of (naive) comprehension in a graph, $G(E,V)$

Tags: set-theory

I am having some trouble interpreting axiom of (naive) comprehension in a graph, $G(V,E)$ Now suppose I define $x\in y \leftrightarrow xEy$, $x, y \in V$. So we now have a structure for set theory.

So how do I interpret the (naive/unbounded/unrestricted) axiom of comprehension in $G$. Originally, based on Jech's book, it reads "If $P$ is a property, then there exist a set $Y$ = {$x$ | $P(x)$}". I tried to interpret this in $G$, and then it reads:

"If $P$ is a property, then there exist a vertex $Y$ = {$x$ | $P(x)$}"

This is really confusing, on the left hand side it is a vertex, on the right hand side, it is a collection/set. But there are no "sets" in $G$, only vertices and edges

How do I resolve this ?

Comment: Anything to the right of a "$\in$" ought to be viewed as a set. So view all vertices as sets

Comment: "then it reads...there is a vertex $Y=$..." no it doesn't read that way! It reads "then there is a set $Y=$...". Why would you think that set  must be a vertex?

Comment: You should read his as "... then there exists a set (i.e., vertex) $y$ such that $x\in y$ (i.e., $xEy$) iff $x$ has property $P$". whether or not this is actually true for your graph $G$ and every $P$ is of course a completely different question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your graph, a vertex $y$ is viewed as the set of its $E$-elements: $\{x\in V:xEy\}$.